# Data from web application not being inserted into mysql db using flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask

[Screen shot of code and terminal window(mySQL)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95vbL.png)

Wrote a code to transfer data from a basic flask web application to a MySQL database using flask_MySQLdb.  But the data isnt being reflected in the MySQLServer.   Please help me debug. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't post links to pictures of code.

Comment: Okay , won't next time. Sorry. Kinda new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your `userDetails = request.form` line is working and successfully getting the data from your HTML form in the format that you expect it to?

Try removing that line and using the following to get the data from each input source:

```
name = request.form.get('name')
email = request.form.get('email')
```

Comment: You we're right. userDetails=request.form doesn't work.